# SELECT all from the table and sum the total for each given date

Tags: sql

Suppose there is a table StackOverflow

**Stackoverflow**

| Date | num_of_questions | num_of_answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/09/01 | 10 | 5 |
| 2022/09/01 | 20 | 5 |
| 2022/09/02 | 25 | 10 |
| 2022/09/02 | 10 | 9 |
| 2022/09/03 | 1 | 8 |
| 2022/09/03 | 8 | 2 |

Is there a way to select all entries within a given date range, and sum all the values for each same day? For instance, return the sum for the range 2022/09/01 - 2022/09/02:
expectation return:

| Date | num_of_questions | num_of_answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/09/01 | 30 | 10 |
| 2022/09/02 | 35 | 19 |

So far I only figured out to write

```
SELECT * FROM Stackoverflow WHERE Date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP BETWEEN'2011/02/01' and '2011/02/02';
```

which return:

| Date | num_of_questions | num_of_answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/09/01 | 10 | 5 |
| 2022/09/01 | 20 | 5 |
| 2022/09/02 | 25 | 10 |
| 2022/09/02 | 10 | 9 |

(but I have not been able to sum this)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, SUM(num_of_questions) as num_of_questions , SUM(num_of_answers) as num_of_answers
FROM Stackoverflow 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2011/02/01' and '2011/02/02' GROUP BY Date;
```

Change your query as above then it will give the expected results.

Comment: I'm going to test it here as well. Give me couple of minutes